# Feeding full image sequences to network or feeding one frame at a time?

Tags: image, tensorflow, sequence, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to implement the following paper: https://research.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/publications/dnn_denoise_author.pdf

My data has the following shape: (7, 512, 512, 1), where 7 is the number of frames in my sequence, 512 is the width and height of an image and 1 the number of channels.

My question is: During training, is it better to feed the convolutional and RNN network the full sequence of images, or feed each frame of a sequence one by one?

I've already tried the first approach, but the results don't look too good. Therefore, is this the "correct" way of processing image sequences, or you have some advice?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Here, author is sending one frame at each time-step, which means, you will have `7` roll-out of `LSTM`, at each roll-out, it accept 1 frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you specify what "here" refers to (the paper that I mentioned, or you wanted to give another paper as example)?

Comment: I have checked this paper last year.

Comment: I understand. Indeed, they seem to use one frame for each time-step, however, they also use their own RNN blocks. In my case, I'm implementing the program in Tensorflow and I saw in multiple posts that for tasks employing image sequences, ConvLSTMCell is suggested. Therefore, wouldn't the full sequence approach be more intuitive, given the ConvLSTMCell. Also, for the roll-out part, do you suggest using a specific RNN cell or have an example code snippet?

Comment: ConvLSTMCell do the same thing(in loose words), that you want, it extract the feature for each step and feed to lstm, which is further rolled-out for 7 steps. However, it is better to use this over others, because it keep the spatial relation along with temporal too.

Comment: i guess, author have used it(convlstm) too, but not sure.

Comment: They are using convolutional RNN blocks, which are not exactly the same thing. Also, no examples of RNN applied on image sequences are available.

Comment: I said in loose words, the one difference is that filter have spatial as well as temporal effect, because it is convolved with input and pass through cell block too. Please point out, if i am wrong here?